# typescript Yup validation or condition with regex using matches problem

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, yup

I'm trying to make sure only one type of special character (semi-colon, comma, or space) is used in a string.

Valid case:

- Can contain alphanumeric letters and numbers
- Can contain special characters : / .
- Can contain only one type of special characters from: space, semi-colon or comma in the string

e.g this should match as it only uses one type of special character (semi-colon):
https://hello.com/example1;https://hello.com.com/example2;https://hello.com.com/example3

This should fail as it mixes two types of special characters (space and semi-colon)

https://hello.com/example1; https://hello.com.com/example2 ;https://hello.com.com/example3

This is my code:

```
const myValidation = yup
.string()
.matches(/^([A-Za-z0-9://,\\.]|[A-Za-z0-9:// \\.]|[A-Za-z0-9://;\\.])+$/, 'Please separate each with a comma, space or semicolon')
.required();
```

When i only have `/^([A-Za-z0-9://,\\.]+$/` it works correctly to only match the string if it has a only a comma as special character:
`https://hello.com/example1,https://hello.com.com/example2,https://hello.com.com/example3`

but as soon as i add the other or conditions `/^([A-Za-z0-9://,\\.]|[A-Za-z0-9:// \\.]|[A-Za-z0-9://;\\.])+$/` it starts allowing for semi-colon and space and comma special characters in the string at the same time (the invalid case)

Comment: Whats the problem? it's a typescript warning? this line of code does not work as intended? could you please show the error

Comment: @Kakiz Hi theres no error but its allowing all the special characters to be used in the string when it should only allow one type (semi-colon, comma or space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the valid cases, you can use a capture group with a backreference `\1` to make sure that the "special character" is the same delimiter between the matches

```
^[A-Za-z0-9:/.]+(?:([ ,;])[A-Za-z0-9:/.]+(?:\1[A-Za-z0-9:/.]+)*)?$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `[A-Za-z0-9:/.]+` Match 1+ of the allowed characters
- `(?:` Non capture group to match as a whole part

  - `([ ,;])` Capture **group 1**, match one of the delimiters
  - `[A-Za-z0-9:/.]+` Match 1+ of the allowed characters
  - `(?:\1[A-Za-z0-9:/.]+)*` Optionally repeat a backreference to the same delimiter and again 1+ of the allowed characters
- `)?` Close the non capture group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/o6z90n/1).

```js
const regex = /^[A-Za-z0-9:/.]+(?:([ ,;])[A-Za-z0-9:/.]+(?:\1[A-Za-z0-9:/.]+)*)?$/;
[
  "https://hello.com/example1;https://hello.com.com/example2;https://hello.com.com/example3",
  "https://hello.com/example1; https://hello.com.com/example2 ;https://hello.com.com/example3",
  "https://hello.com/example1"
].forEach(s =>
  console.log(`${regex.test(s)} --> ${s}`)
);
```

---

If there should be at least a single delimiter present, you could shorten the pattern to:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9:/.]+([ ,;])[A-Za-z0-9:/.]+(?:\1[A-Za-z0-9:/.]+)*$
```

---

If the strings should start with `http://` or `https://` you could use:

```
^https?:\/\/[A-Za-z0-9:/.]+(?:([ ,;])https?:\/\/[A-Za-z0-9:/.]+(?:\1[A-Za-z0-9:/.]+)*)?$
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/x5TiB6/1).

Answer (score 0):

#### Is only one

```
function isOnlyOne() {
  let s = "zy,,aemnofgbcjkhilpqasdfrstuvrhfwx";
  console.log([...new Set(s.split("").filter(e => e.match(/[;, ]/)))].length==1);
  //return [...new Set(s.split("").filter(e => e.match(/[a-z]/)))].length==26;
}
```